# 3 parallel tasks each awaiting their own result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to try using background workers. I am interesting to use `async/await`.
I have 3 parallel tasks.

```
private async void RunDownloadsAsync()
{
     Task taskDelay1 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(10000));
     Task taskDelay2 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(15000)); 
     Task taskDelay3 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(20000)); 
     await ???
}
```

Let's assume each of these Tasks changes the value of 3 Labels (`label1`, `label2`, `label3`) on a form when they are done. i.e. all labels are set to "Pending" and when each task is done, their corresponding label value will change to "Finished".

I would like to `await` each task accordingly so that they each do their own corresponding task. That means if `taskDelay1`'s job is finished set `label1`'s text to "Finished" while `taskDelay2` and `taskDelay3` are still pending. But if I put 3 `awaits` there, the program will wait for all of them to finish their task and then continue the rest of the code.

How can I continue the rest of the code in which each label only waits for its own task to finish and then decide what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Task.WhenAll` method to wait for all of them and `ContinueWith` to execute operation when the task is completed.

```
 Task taskDelay1 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(10000)).ContinueWith(t => SetLabel());
 Task taskDelay2 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(15000)).ContinueWith(t => SetLabel()); 
 Task taskDelay3 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(20000)).ContinueWith(t => SetLabel()); 
 await Task.WhenAll(taskDelay1, taskDelay2, taskDelay3);
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've updated the answer to include `ContinueWith` to set the labels

Comment: does `SetLabel` have to be an `async` method two?

Comment: @Pedram: No. It will run synchronous.

Answer (score 4):

There's an important distinction between *parallel* and *concurrent*. Parallel refers to using multiple threads to do CPU-bound work. Parallelism is one form of concurrency, but not the only one. Another form of concurrency is asynchrony, which can do non-CPU-bound work without introducing multiple threads.

In your case, "downloads" imply an I/O-bound operation, which should be done with asynchrony and *not* parallelism. Check out the `HttpClient` class for asynchronous downloads. You can use `Task.WhenAll` for asynchronous concurrency:

```
private async Task RunDownload1Async()
{
  label1.Text = "Pending";
  await Task.Delay(10000);
  label1.Text = "Finished";
}

private async Task RunDownload2Async()
{
  label2.Text = "Pending";
  await Task.Delay(15000);
  label2.Text = "Finished";
}

private async Task RunDownload3Async()
{
  label3.Text = "Pending";
  await Task.Delay(20000);
  label3.Text = "Finished";
}

private async Task RunDownloadsAsync()
{
  await Task.WhenAll(RunDownload1Async(), RunDownload2Async(), RunDownload3Async());
}
```

This approach avoids creating unnecessary threads and also does not use outdated techniques (`ContinueWith`, `Dispatcher.Invoke`). That said, it's not perfect, since the GUI logic is mixed with the operational logic in the `RunDownloadNAsync` methods. A better approach would be to use `IProgress<T>` and `Progress<T>` for updating the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute an action after the `Task` is completed. Note that you might need to call [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the expression in the `ContinueWith` to prevent cross-thread calls.

Here is a sample from a WPF application, using `Dispatcher.Invoke`:

```
private static async void Async()
{
    Task taskDelay1 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000))
                      .ContinueWith(x => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.label1.Content = "One done"));

    Task taskDelay2 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1500))
                      .ContinueWith(x => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.label2.Content = "Two done"));

    Task taskDelay3 = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(2000))
                      .ContinueWith(x => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.label3.Content = "Three done"));

    await Task.WhenAll(taskDelay1, taskDelay2, taskDelay3);
}
```

As [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035029/dirk) suggested, an alternative to calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` would be to use a task scheduler, e.g. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` if you're on the UI thread.

Comment: An alternative to calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` would be to use a task scheduler, e.g. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` if you're on the UI thread.

Comment: @Dirk: Added it with attribution, if you are okay with it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman sorry your answer seems correct to but the other gentleman posted earlier.

Comment: @Pedram: No problem. Your upvote makes it all well. Thanks. I needed more time to have a decent post ready.